# Why is the kafka consumer consuming the same message hundreds of times?

Tags: apache-kafka

I see from the logs that exact same message is consumed by the 665 times. Why does this happen?

I also see this in the logs

```
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. 
This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies 
that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session 
timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

Consumer properties

```
group.id=someGroupId
bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
enable.auto.commit=false
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
session.timeout.ms=30000
max.poll.records=20
```

PS: Is it possible to consume only a specific number of messages like 10 or 50 or 100 messages from the 1000 that are in the queue?
I was looking at 'fetch.max.bytes' config, but it seems like it is for a message size rather than number of messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer lies in the understanding of the following concepts:

- session.timeout.ms
- heartbeats
- max.poll.interval.ms

In your case, your consumer receives a message via poll() but is not able to complete the processing in max.poll.interval.ms time. Therefore, it is assumed hung by the Broker and re-balancing of partitions happen due to which this consumer loses the ownership of all partitions. It is marked dead and is no longer part of a consumer group.

Then when your consumer completes the processing and calls poll() again two things happen:

1. Commit fails as the consumer no longer owns the partitions.
2. Broker identifies that the consumer is up again and therefore a re-balance is triggered and the consumer again joins the Consumer Group, start owning partitions and request messages from the Broker. Since the earlier message was not marked as committed (refer #1 above, failed commit) and is pending processing, the broker delivers the same message to consumer again.

Consumer again takes a lot of time to process and since is unable to finish processing in less than max.poll.interval.ms, 1. and 2. keep repeating in a loop.

To fix the problem, you can increase the max.poll.interval.ms to a large enough value based on how much time your consumer needs for processing. Then your consumer will not get marked as dead and will not receive duplicate messages. 
However, the real fix is to check your processing logic and try to reduce the processing time.

Comment: Is it possible to consume only a certain number of messages? Say for example consume 100 messages rather than all the messages that have arrived since the last poll.

Comment: Set max.poll.records to 100

Comment: Refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The fix is described in the message you pasted:

> You can address this either by increasing the session  timeout or by
>   reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with
>   max.poll.records.

The reason is a timeout is reached before your consumer is able to process and commit the message. When your Kafka consumer "commits", it's basically acknowledging receipt of the previous message, advancing the offset, and therefore moving onto the next message. But if that timeout is passed (as is the case for you), the consumer's commit isn't effective because it's happening too late; then the next time the consumer asks for a message, it's given the same message

Some of your options are to:

1. Increase `session.timeout.ms=30000`, so the consumer has more time
   process the messages
2. Decrease the `max.poll.records=20` so the consumer has less messages it'll need to work on before the timeout occurs. But this doesn't really apply to you because your consumer is already only just working on a single message
3. Or turn on `enable.auto.commit`, which probably also isn't the best solution for you because it might result in dropping messages though, as mentioned below:

   > If we allowed offsets to auto commit as in the previous example
   >   messages would be considered consumed after they were given out by the
   >   consumer, and it would be possible that our process could fail after
   >   we have read messages into our in-memory buffer but before they had
   >   been inserted into the database.
   >   Source: https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: My question is why is the same message consumed so many times? A commit has failed but there should be only one copy of the message.

Comment: well what else do you want the consumer to do? It's gonna keep doing what it does best, which is attempt to consume messages by asking for a message, processing, then commit it, then asking for another message to work on. The consumer doesn't even know it has been getting the same message. It just keeps saying "gimme a message", "ok I'll work on it,", "ok done, commit the offset". The problem here is that when it says "commit the offset", the timeout has already elapsed, and the offset isn't advancing. But he doesn't know that, so he continues and asks for the next message to work on

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, When consumer was start pulling messages from Kafka topic & it took more time while processing the message. Consumer was failed to send successful acknowledgement to Kafka topic within a default threshold time. When acknowledgement failed for a specific message, that message becomes active & available for next poll. I have fixed this issue by overriding default consumer max poll interval configuration to 10 mins. Default max.poll.interval.ms is 5 mins.